# Minimal sets, Perfect sets, Exceptional sets and Foliations

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, cantor-set, foliations, transversality

The first image is taken from **Geometric Theory of Foliations**, Book by **A. Lins Neto** and **César Camacho**, Chapter **3**, Page **53**.

The second image is taken from **Geometry, Dynamics And Topology Of Foliations: A First Course**, Book by **Bruno Scárdua** and **Carlos Arnoldo Morales Rojas**, Chapter **3**, Page **56**.

In the first image, statement $(c)$ in theorem $7$ the condition $\mu \cap \partial \Sigma = \varnothing$ is not assumed while in proposition $3.2$, in the second image, it is to get the same result.

How could this be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the definition of a minimal subset of a foliation?

Comment: @Didier Let $M$ be a manifold with a foliation $F$. A subset $\mu$ of $M$ is minimal if it satisfies the following properties: $1)$ $\mu$ is non-empty, closed and invariant (invariant $=$ it is a union of leaves). $2$ if $N$ is a subset of $\mu$ and it closed and invariant, then either $N=\phi$ or $N=\mu$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also provide a definition for the notion of perfect sets?

Comment: @Didier it is a closed set without isolated points. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set#:~:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,as%20the%20derived%20set%20of%20.